# Batch - xcopy files older than x minutes

Tags: batch-file, time, copy

after a new file creation time of 20 min I want to copy all files with the extensions `.txt`  from Folder `New` to Folder `Target`. (I want to copy olny files are older than 20 min)

So far, it looks like this:

```
set hh=%TIME:~0,2%
set mm=%TIME:~3,2%
set ss=%TIME:~6,2%

set /a sum_sec=%hh% * 3600 + %mm% * 60 + %ss% -300

set /a h=%sum_sec% / 3600
set /a m=(%sum_sec%/60) - 60 * %h%
set /a s=%sum_sec% - 60 * (%sum_sec%/60)
IF %h% LSS 10 set h=0%h%
IF %m% LSS 10 set m=0%m%
IF %s% LSS 10 set s=0%s%

set new_time=%h%:%m%:%s%
```

So far I've only delete files that are older than 20 minutes:

```
forfiles /P "C:\Users\Desktop\Start" /S /M *.txt /C "cmd /c if @ftime LSS %new_time% del /F /Q @path"
```

My Question now is how can I copy new files from Folder `New` to Folder `Target` after 20 minutes ?

Best regs

Comment: older in meaning of creation or modification?

Comment: Hi. Older in meaning of creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [FileTimeFilter.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/FileTimeFilterJS.bat)  - it is capable to filter files by different time conditions.So (it should be in the same directory):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('
  call FileTimeFiler.bat "New" -mm -20 -direction before -filetime created
') do (
   copy "%%~f#" "Target"
)
```

EDIT . Filter txt files

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('
  call FileTimeFiler.bat "New" -mm -20 -direction before -filetime created ^| findstr /e /i ".txt"
') do (
   copy "%%~f#" "Target"
)
```

Comment: Hi. Is it possible to search and let copy only files with a extension .txt ? I try `"C:\Users\Desktop\New\*.txt" -mm -20 -direction before -filetime created`

But it fails and get a Runtime Error.